# How to build VSCode to be used in the browser?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I found many projects that required a server. My question how do I start Visual Studio Code like any other jQuery/React/Angular library? How do I start it from the browser without using a server?

I know that I will need to provide the files using a script.

I don't need the extension marketplace, terminal and similar. I only need the files tab on the left, the search tab, and the editor itself. The editor is Monaco, I found out. But I didn't find something that also contains the files panel and the tabs switcher (The list of opened files).

There are projects like [code-server](https://github.com/coder/code-server), but it requires a server. It also should be executed by our clients, so I don't want resources or security risks on the server.

So how do I compile and embed Visual Studio Code into a Web page to be served by a static HTML server?

Comment: VSCode is an IDE, not a library - a webserver is a different software. What do you expect it to do? Some web development will naturally require a webserver.

Comment: But it's written in JavaScript so technically it can be executed by using only HTML and JS

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein - Yes, the majority of VS Code can be run in a browser (as demonstrated by stackblitz and codesandbox and even the TypeScript playground); it's an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app, so the UI runs in browser tech. At least some of those projects are open source, as is [VS Code itself](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode). But much of their functionality (including running builds and such) is not run in the browser, it's server-side and reflected to the browser.

Comment: I only need the file explorer. The search panel, the files tab, and the editor itself. The editor itself it is not a problem it’s Monaco

Comment: Are you asking for [vscode.dev](https://vscode.dev/) ? That opens VSCode in your browser.

Comment: I do remember there are giuds on how to run VS code in browser.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I'm asking to develop a vscode.dev for my own clients. I will provide the files, and the extensions for it. No need for terminal, or any connectivity. No need to run or debug. Just see the files.

Comment: You will possibly find something in the documentation. What about this: [VS Code for the web](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#vs-code-for-the-web)